# Why setInterval inside a while loop become an infinite loop (JS)?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, setinterval, infinite-loop

I tried to call a delayed "one" call or a "one or two?" question, but instead the function started running indefinitely, although without setInterval everything worked fine.

```
quester2()
function quester2() {
  for (i = 0; i <= finalCount; i++) {
    let K = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2);
    if (K == 1) {
      setInterval(function () { console.log("one"); }, 1000);
      finalCount += 1;
      allIterations += 1;
      setInterval(function () { console.log("one or two?"); }, 1000);
    } else {
      setInterval(function () { console.log("one or two?"); }, 1000);
      allIterations += 1;
    }
  }
  console.log(finalCount);
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: What is `finalCount`, what is the initial value?

Comment: It's not `setInterval` - your `if` branch leads to an infinite loop. You randomly select whether to prolong the loop or not. `setInterval` is irrelevant - it would not affect the execution, as it just delays the function you give it to be executed *later*. And *definitely* after the loop.

Comment: You most likely do not have an infinite loop, only if you are very unlucky. But you will have quite a lot of intervals running and printing nonesense because you never tell them to stop,

Comment: The `for` condition itself is causing the infinite loop. Change `i <= finalCount` to `i < finalCount`. That `<=` in there is the logical error.

Comment: @GetSet no, there is no logical error and no infinite loop. < vs <=  is just a difference of one iteration.

Comment: @luk2302 Yeah on second thought there really isnt

Comment: setInterval causes a piece of code to run over and over again, until you clear it.  It is not suitable for delaying a single execution - for that use setTimeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no infinite loop, your code may just randomly take more iterations compared to previous runs. You sometimes increase `finalCount` which is involved in the condition of the `for` loop.

What may appear like an infinite loop is the fact that you run quite a lot of setIntervals and never clear them. But if you carefully check your console you basically instantly after invoking the function see two outputs for the last two log statements. A second after that you start seeing an infinite number of "one" and "one or two?".

```
quester2()
```

> 0
> 1
> one or two?